# PHP - transform array into the new one

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

**CURRENT ARRAY:**

```
stdClass Object (
[name1] => Someting very useful
[text1] => Description of something useful
[url1] => link.to/useful
[name2] => Someting very useful2
[text2] => Description of something useful2
[url2] => link.to/useful2
[name3] => Someting very useful3
[text3] => Description of something useful3
[url3] => link.to/useful3
)
```

**I NEED:**
To create multidimensional array where keys like name1, text1, url1 (and so on) will be putted into own array. How to accomplish that?

Comment: You have an object - instance of stdClass. It is not array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want:

```
$array = array_chunk((array)$object, $chunkSize = 3, $preserveKeys = true);
```

(`$object` is your object above)

This will cast your object to an array, and split it into smaller arrays of 3 elements each

Comment: Good answer as long as properties are in order and consistent.

Answer (score 1):

Well;

```
$array = (array) $object;
```

Comment: Not really what the OP is asking for. I believe they want it broken down into multidimensional array based off the number at the end of the property. So all the 1's go together, all the 2's go together, etc...

Answer (score 1):

This would be very versatile even if you don't have consistent input, like exactly three properties per child. Also the properties in the object don't have to be in any particular order.

```
//$obj is the object you have in the question
$objects = array();
foreach($obj as $key => $val) {
    $result = preg_match('%([a-zA-Z]+)([0-9]+)%', $key,$matches);
    $new_key = $matches[2];
    $property = $matches[1];
    if(!isset($objects[$new_key])) {
        $objects[$new_key] = array();
    }
    $objects[$new_key][$property] = $val;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$array = array();
$c = count($object) / 3;
(Array) $object;

for($i = 1; $i <= $c; $i++){

    $array[$i]['name' + $i] = $object['name' + $i];
    $array[$i]['text' + $i] = $object['text' + $i];
    $array[$i]['url' + $i] = $object['url' + $i];

}
```

Comment: Please can you provide some explanation of your answer.